#  Goedel's number from the Incompleteness Theorem

Tags: lo.logic

Does anybody know the exact number from the Goedel's Incompleteness Theorem? Is it written down somewhere? Is there a computer program to generate it?

Comment: What number do you mean?  Given a sufficiently strong recursive system of axioms, the Goedel number of a statement that is neither proved nor disproved from the system of axioms? 

Comment: I have voted to close because this question is not in the scope of the site, as described in the FAQ linked at the top of the page. The proof of the incompleteness theorem is completely constructive and so, in principle, you could follow it step by step to write down a Goedel number of the Goedel sentence, given a Goedel numbering of formulas. However, it is unlikely that anyone has done so, because the actual number would be quite large. 

Comment: You can use a Gödel numbering in which a given formula (e.g. your favorite Gödel sentence) has Gödel number equal to a given number (e.g. 17). So the answer to your question: the exact number you are looking for can be any number, it all depends on the Gödel numbering you use.

Comment: I would be interested to see an answer to the question, if it provided the actual G&ouml;del number of the original "I am not provable" statement using G&ouml;del's coding scheme, which is of historical interest. I would view such an aswer as fundamentally similar to the results I have seen, published in one of the MAA journals, to compute the digits of the transcendental number Cantor produced in his original diagonalization against the algebraic reals. 

Comment: I would be interested to know if anyone has done this crazy thing, too. Please don't close. I just checked Russell O'Connors formalization in Coq (http://r6.ca/Goedel/goedel1.html), but unfortunately his program cannot do it (see section 8 of his web page).

Comment: @Joel: Google turns up http://tachyos.org/godel/Godel_number.html but I have no idea whether that uses the same coding as the original paper. The main page for that project is http://tachyos.org/godel.html . 

Comment: @Joel @Carl: tachyos's coding is not the same as Goedel's original coding.  If I recall, John Harrison claims that even my Cantor pairing coding produces codes that become so large that it would not be feasible to write down the answer.  Goedel's original coding is even worse using exponential coding.  I would expect the code used in Goedel's original proof wouldn't fit in the universe.